# Как создать один массив из двух?

Tags: java, массивы, инспекция-кода, потоки-данных

Заданы массивы `А(n)` и `В(m)`. Сформировать массив `С(n+m)`, элементами которого являются `n` элементов массива `A`, за которыми следуют `m` элементов массива `B`. Можете посмотреть код, я просто не уверенна, что все правильно сделала.

В консоль выдает только `1 2 3 4`.

```java
public class six {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] A = {"1", "2"};
        String[] B = {"3", "4"};
        String[] C = new String[A.length + B.length];

        int f = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            C[f] = A[i];
            f += 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
            C[f] = B[i];
            f += 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(C[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: почему не уверена или в чем проблема?

Comment: как-то слишком легко для такого задания

Comment: как-то легко или сложно не является проблемой. Опишите проблему, что у вас не работает или что работает неправильно.

Comment: Всё нормально. Только имена переменных (и методов) принято писать с маленькой буквы (в отличие от имен классов, интерфейсов  и перечислений). А код `C[f] = A[i];  f +=1;` можно записать проще: `c[f++] = a[i];`

Comment: а почему "только 1 2 3 4", должно что-то еще?

Comment: Все правильно, только следует называть переменные более понятными названиями. Класс - с большой буквы. Как сказали раньше, лучше не `f +=1`, а `C[f++];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас задача связана с конкатенацией массивов. Проблема в том, что вы не можете прицепить один массив к другому или же расширить массив до требуемой длины. Потому, что длина массива фиксирована. Вам нужно создать новый массив и скопировать туда элементы массивов последовательно. Что вы и сделали, только зачем делать это вручную, такой код потом трудно использовать и модифицировать. Если можно использовать потоки из массивов, то эта задача решается так:

```
String[] C = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(A), Arrays.stream(B))
                   .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class six{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {"1", "2"};
        int[] B = {"3", "4"};
        int[] C = [A.length + B.length];

        int f = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            C[f] = C[f] + A[i];
            f +=1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
             C[f] = C[f] + B[i];
            f +=1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(C[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам стринг?

Answer (score 1):

```java
String[] A = {"1", "2"};
String[] B = {"3", "4"};

String[] C = Stream.of(A, B)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(C)); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

```java
String[] A = {"1", "2"};
String[] B = {"3", "4"};

String[] C = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(A), Arrays.stream(B))
        .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(C)); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
String[] a = {"1", "2"};
String[] b = {"3", "4"};

String[] c = new String[a.length + b.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
```

Вывод:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4]